# Upgrade Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo)

Tags: upgrade

I would like to upgrade Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) desktop edition to latest one. Can anyone suggest what will the latest available version and steps to upgrade. Tried but not able to upgrade with the source lists which i got.

Is there any possibility to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) to 21.10.

Note : We are not using LTS version. If possible let us know the possible steps to upgrade.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 had one *supported* upgrade path; to the next release or Ubuntu 19.10, however that closed when 19.10 reached EOL.  If it's a desktop system, I'd *upgrade via re-install*

Comment: Also please note:  If your architecture is *i386*, there is no upgrade path at all.  You can return (*upgrade via re-install*) to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which still supports the *i386* architecture.   You didn't say if desktop release; but I'm involved with QA-testing & thus switch releases many times using the *upgrade via re-install*; my last was a no-longer required for support 21.04 which changed to *jammy* (22.04).  I regularly *bump* between releases (ie. current QA-testing is mostly *focal* (20.04.4) & *jammy* (22.04) but you didn't say what type of install (*best with desktop*)

Comment: While it is possible to upgrade, it would be much simpler to fresh install Ubuntu 21.10 (supported until July 2022). Alternatively, install 20.04 LTS, which is supported till April 2025.

Comment: I just noted you did say (*desktop edition*).  You can re-install Ubuntu (and *flavors*) without impacting your data files, losing configurations (*where done on a user and not system level*) and have the install automatically re-install your *manually installed* packages.  Backup your system, Boot the release you want to install & use "*Something else*" then select existing partitions but do **not** format any. The no-format causes a *upgrade via re-install* to be triggered. It is designed to cope with Ubuntu repository software & you may get errors if packages aren't available on new release

Comment: ... but the install should succeed.  During 2019 a number of things reached EOL; eg. Qt4 was removed as were any packages that relied on it (which weren't ported to Qt5), likewise many python2 were removed (again if not ported to python3) so errors are likely if you were using packages no longer supported; or have 3rd party packages installed. Regardless of error (some packages could not be re-installed) the install will boot & be what you want (*as long as you didn't format*), but backup always as always; it's easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. It's really useful.